# Run a command in Laravel on every page load

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to load a command with Laravel on each page load;

```
$mail_count = mail::where('to_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('read', '=', '0')->count('read');
```

What would be the best way to do this? This then needs to output the result in the master template for the page.

Comment: It will be better to put this in the constructor of the Controller.

Comment: Which controller? Would I need to put it into all or just the main controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a view composer for master template, for example:

```
// app/providers/ComposerServiceProvider.php
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer(
        'layouts.master', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\MasterComposer'
    );
}
```

Then create the Composer class:

```
namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Auth;
use App\Mail;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class MasterComposer
{
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $mail_count = Mail::where('to_id', Auth::user()->id)
                          ->where('read', 0)
                          ->count('read');
        $view->with('mail_count', $mail_count);
    }
}
```

Finally, you can use {{ $mail_count }} in your master view to print out the result. So, in this case, what it's doing is, whenever your `views\layouts\master.blade.php` will be rendered the `compose` method will be called and `$mail_count` will be attached into the view. Make sure to use the exact name for the view, I've used `layouts.master` (views/layouts/master.blade.php) for this example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use it in a laravel provider
go to the `AppServiceProvider.php` inside the `boot` function paste variable

```
$mail_count = mail::where('to_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('read', '=', '0')->count('read');
```

then you can do it with one of the options:

1.

```
view()->composer('*', function($view) use($mail_count){
    $view->with('mail_count', $mail_count);
});
```

2.

```
view()->share('mail_count', $mail_count);
```